# Removing Duplicate Numbers from an Array and Adding them to the end at c++

Tags: c++, arrays

i have an array in `data.txt` file like 9 3 9 4 5 4 3 7 1 9 6

i need to find duplicate numbers and remove them from the array.

After that i need to collect them at the end of the array.

i wrote a code and the output is 9 3 4 5 7 1 6 9 3 4 9, but i need to put the duplicated numbers in array, in the sequence they appear in the original array.

So i need to get `{ 9, 3, 4, 5, 7, 1, 6, 9, 4, 3, 9 }` as output.

**What can i do with  the code to reach my goal ?**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
#define SZ 11
int main(){
    ifstream fs("data.txt");
    if (!fs)
        return 0;
    int a[SZ];
    for (int i = 0; i < SZ; ++i)
        fs >> a[i];
    for (int k=0; k<SZ; k++) {
        for (int j=k+1; j< SZ ; j++) {
            if (a[j]==a[k]) {
                for (int l=j; l<SZ-1; l++) {
                    a[l]=a[l+1];
                }
                a[10]=a[k];
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < SZ; ++i)
        cout << a[i];
    return 1;}
```

Comment: I don't suppose `std::sort`-ing the array, then running `std::unique` over it is an option.

Comment: I expect it's homework so everything has to be written like it's C code rather than using proper C++ idioms.

Comment: Do you in fact need to get `{9,3,4,5,7,1,6}` for your sample input?

Comment: `unique` wouldn't maintain the order of the dupes, which the OP said was required.

Comment: Sorry but, should removing duplicates from 9 3 9 4 5 4 3 7 1 9 6 result in 9 3 4 5 7 1 6 ??  By the way,  are the numbers you read bound (max, min) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one strategy.

Keep the notion of whether an entry is duplicate or not in a parallel array.

Print the numbers that are not duplicates first.

Then print the numbers that are duplicates.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
#define SZ 11
int main()
{
   ifstream fs("data.txt");
   if (!fs)
      return 0;
   int a[SZ];
   int isDuplicate[SZ];
   for (int i = 0; i < SZ; ++i)
   {
      fs >> a[i];
      isDuplicate[i] = false;
   }

   for (int k=0; k<SZ; k++) {
      for (int j=k+1; j< SZ ; j++) {
         if (a[j]==a[k])
         {
            isDuplicate[j] = true;
         }
      }
   }

   // Print the non-duplicates
   for (int i = 0; i < SZ; ++i)
   {
      if ( !isDuplicate[i] )
         cout << a[i] << " ";
   }

   // Print the duplicates
   for (int i = 0; i < SZ; ++i)
   {
      if ( isDuplicate[i] )
         cout << a[i] << " ";
   }
   cout << endl;

   // Not sure why you have 1 as the return value.
   // It should be 0 for successful completion.
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the order, you have to compare each number to the previous ones instead of comparing it to the next ones. Your program becomes :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
#define SZ 11
int main(){
ifstream fs("data.txt");
    if (!fs)
        return 0;
    int a[SZ];
    for (int i = 0; i < SZ; ++i)
        fs >> a[i];
    // kk limits the number of iteration, k points to the number to test
    for (int k=0, kk=0; kk<SZ; kk++, k++) {
        for (int j=0; j< k ; j++) {
            if (a[j]==a[k]) {
                for (int l=k; l<SZ-1; l++) {
                    a[l]=a[l+1];
                }
                a[SZ - 1]=a[j];
                // a[k] is a new number and must be controlled at next iteration
                k -= 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < SZ; ++i)
        cout << a[i];
    return 1;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP's (@kuvvetkolu) original example has O(SZ^3) complexity, which is brutal. @RSahu's solution is O(SZ^2), an improvement (and correct), but this should not require O(N^2)...

Here's a version that incurs only space overhead (assuming O(1) hash table lookup). You can use a `unordered_set` (a hash table) to track whether you've already seen a particular number, put it in the appropriate vector and then merge the vectors at the end.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::ifstream fs("data.txt");
    if (!fs)
        throw std::runtime_error("File not found!");

    std::vector<int> a;
    std::vector<int> dups;
    std::unordered_set<int> seen;

    int d;
    while (fs) {
        fs >> d;
        if (seen.find(d) == seen.end())
        {
            a.push_back(d);
            seen.insert(d);
        }
        else
        {
            dups.push_back(d);
        }
    }

    a.insert(a.end(), dups.begin(), dups.end());

    for (auto n : a)
        std::cout << n << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm inclined to try out a solution that uses std::remove_if and has a deduping unary predicate. That should retain the order of your duplicate elements.

Comment: Unfortunately, `remove_if` is not guaranteed to move the duplicated objects to the end. It leaves the objects past the returned iterator in an unspecified state.

Comment: `remove_copy_if` can work this way, however it has to output into a separate container